# How to combine a boolean mask and slice object to slice a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I have a large dataframe and a function that performs some operations on the dataframe. One of the arguments of the function is a mask.

```
def func(df, mask):
   if mask is None:
      mask = slice(None) # first print is fast, but the second does not work.
      mask = np.ones(len(df), dtype=bool) # this makes the first print very slow. 

   print(df.loc[mask, 'A'].sum())
   high_val = (df.val > 100) & mask
   low_val = (df.val <= 100) & mask
   print(df.loc[high_val, 'A'].sum(), df.loc[low_val, 'A'].sum())
```

The code I copied above does not work when mask is None (there is no mask).

I could make mask a numpy array with all values equal to True when None is passed in, but this makes the first slicing  (df.loc[mask, 'A']) really slow.

I could make mask=slice(None). This makes the first slicing  (df.loc[mask, 'A']) fast, but then (df.val > 100) & mask would not work.

How should I pass in a mask to make it work for both cases?

Comment: what does the df look like? using simulated data: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(100), 'val': np.arange(100)*50}) your code ran without error.

Comment: @warped Thanks for checking. Comment out the second line of mask and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rearrange your logical expressions and circumvent the problem:

```
def func(df, mask):

    if mask is None:
        print(df.A.sum())
        mask = True
    else:
        print(df.loc[mask, 'A'].sum())

    high_val = (df.val > 100) & mask
    low_val = (df.val <= 100) & mask    

    print(df.loc[high_val, 'A'].sum(), df.loc[low_val, 'A'].sum())
```